# mysqldump on windows with mysql 8 community

Tags: windows-10, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysqldump

I have MySQL 8.0.26 installed but when I type mysqldump in PowerShell I get a `The term 'mysqldump' is not recognized` error.

When I open up the installer everything is installed.

Back in the day mysqldump would have been in the bin\ directory of a MySQL install but that is no longer the case. Here's `C:\Program Files\MySQL`:

[image]

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0` has a bin directory inside it but no mysqldump inside that bin directory.

Here's `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL`:

[image]

Is there a more modern way to do SQL dumps these days or something?

Comment: The tool in question should be located within the MySQL Workbench folder.  Have you searched the entire root directory for the file?

Comment: Verify the tool does not exist within [this](https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.0/mysql-8.0.29-winx64.zip) file.

Comment: did you find out what's going on. i have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You must check inside of the `MySQL Server 8.0` directory.

In my case, the `mysqldump` file is located here:
`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe`

It is advisable to add this `bin` directory to the global PATH variable.

Comment: Is mysqldump part of the mysqladmin.exe executable?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the typo.